# How can I click on an HTML row then show the values of the row in input texts

Tags: angularjs, html

How can I click on an HTML row then show the values of the row in input texts to able the user to edit them.

in controller :

```
$scope.data = [];


$scope.selectedMember = { Code: "", Latin: "", Local: "" }; //new property
$scope.showInEdit = function (member)
{
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
}
```

in ng-repeat :

```
<table border="1" ng-hide="Hide">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Latin Description</th>
                <th>Local Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:Code | filter:Latin | filter:Local track by $index">

                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</a></td>
                <td>{{c.L_Desc}}</td>
                <td>{{c.A_Desc}}</td>
                <!--<td><input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="Edit(c)"/> </td>-->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In HTML :

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" autofocus ng-model="selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latin Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Latin.L_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Local Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Local.A_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks lot

Comment: Rather than clicking the row, I think you should have a button that executed a function to replace that row with one with text inputs, and a button to save it which would make an ajax call to whatever you use to save your data in and return to the original structure of the table.

Comment: You might take a look at [this](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your scope variables in function like

```
$scope.Latin.L_Desc = c.example;
```

After that you'll see these values in input fields.

Comment: kindly can you provide me more details, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show values in this code

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" autofocus ng-model="selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Latin Description</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Latin.L_Desc"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Local Description</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="35" ng-model="Local.A_Desc"></td>
        </tr>
```

Then your object must be like this :

```
$scope.selectedMember = { Code: "", Latin: {A_Desc:""}, Local: {L_Desc:""} };
```

And in controller function

```
 $scope.showInEdit = function (member)
{
    $scope.selectedMember.Latin.L_Desc = member;
}
```

Comment: it works fine BUT the filter now is not working, i cannot write any thing in the "Code" input text to search in the html table, any idea, thanks in advance

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:selectedMember.code">

name it like "selectedMember.code"

Comment: the filter works on the html table after clicking the mouse on a row and the data shown in input texts, I want the user to be able filter before clicking the mouse on any row, i cannot write any thing in any input texts . any idea

Comment: If you want to filter then you've to filter array in controller. The filter you are using it's work after some operation like you are clicking then works.
Filter works on array you have to make sure.

Comment: Kindly can you inform me with details , i am new in Angular.  The table is filled from the database, thanks

Comment: Try create fiddle or something else so that I work on your code.
In this way I can't understand.

Comment: can I send you text files through skype? or access teamviewer